# What library to use for CSV import in c#

Tags: c#, csv

I've looked at FileHelpers v2.0 but there is a serious problem woth that. I cannot define a class that maps to the record in the source/detination file.

The reason is I don't know what file I'm going to get. A big part of my program is mapping the file's fields to the database's fields... I don't know how many fields there wil be, nor wich will need to be imported.

I have no intention on rolling my own lib, especially since I have no control over the files that are going to be fed to my program.

Any solutions tot his?

Dennis

Comment: You can't build a system to do **everything**; you have to have *some* specifications.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the [Fast CSV reader on the CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/CsvReader.aspx).  It helped me with my project a while ago.  Its really easy to use, and is quite good.

Comment: Yep! This is what I need. Not complex as FileHelper yet correct for even badly made csv's. Thanks for pointing it out Gabriel!

Answer (score 3):

You can use ADO.NET to directly read the .CSV file into a DataTable.  If you don't know how many fields will exist in advance, this can be a useful means of working with the data.  This also has the advantage of not requiring any external libraries.

For details, please see [Deborah Kurata's article on the subject](http://msmvps.com/blogs/deborahk/archive/2009/08/25/reading-comma-delimited-files.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

[StreamReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.aspx) has been fast enough for me for pretty much every text file, though you are pretty screwed if you cant even guarantee value ordering.

Comment: that is why my program needs a function to define the mapping.

Comment: OK... perhaps I am missing your meaning. Are you looking for a programmatic solution to importing CSV data into a database, or a tool that will let you define source (CSV) and destination values (DB) per file and import the data?